# How to modify the legends produced by "Expressions" in the PlotLegends option

Tags: plotting, legending

I'm creating a fairly simple plot with a bunch of similar graphs in it. It looks something like this (but with more than two functions):

```
Plot[{x + 2, x - 2}, {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {{-3.1, 3.1}, {-4, 4}},
    PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

And it produces the following plot, as expected:

[image]

But I want each equation in the legend to say "$y=\ldots$", i.e. I want to produce the following:

```
Plot[{x + 2, x - 2}, {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {{-3.1, 3.1}, {-4, 4}},
    PlotLegends -> {"y=x+2", "y=x-2"}]
```

[image]

As you can see, I manually typed all equations into `PlotLegends`. But I don't want to do that, because in my actual application I have more than two functions on the same graph. Is it possible to still use `"Expressions"` in `PlotLegends`, but to somehow modify all of them at once, because I want to add "y=" to all of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could put `y =` in the functions

```
Plot[{y = x + 2, y = x - 2}, {x, -3, 3}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-3.1, 3.1}, {-4, 4}}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is:

```
f = {x + 2, x - 2};
Plot[f, {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {{-3.1, 3.1}, {-4, 4}},  PlotLegends -> {Row[{"y", #}, "="] & /@ f}]
```